# Any way to notate the outputs in function arguments?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a function

```
void doStuff(vector<int> &a, int b, vector<int> &c> {
    c = vector<int>(a.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b;
    }
}
```

obviously, upon seeing the function, we know that "c" is the output.

For anybody who hasn't seen the function definition though, it remains a mystery unless i name c something like "output_c". Maybe I'm just being vein but I don't like naming things "ouput_xxx", is there any syntax candy for letting the user of the function know that its supposed to be the output?

Comment: Why don't you return by-value, instead of using an out-parameter? Also, your indey should be of type `size_t`.

Comment: that example only has one return item but I might have more. Also I'm not too fond of the "maybe" factor of RVO.

Comment: In that case, we have `std::tuple`. BTW: Your input-argument should be a constant reference.

Comment: I don't see why one should worry about people calling a function without knowing what it does.

Comment: A common convention is to use `const&` for arguments that won't be mutated and plain references or pointers for out-arguments. FWIW, the Google style guide mandates that out-arguments should be pointers and all reference arguments must be `const&`.

Comment: @Pradhan FWIW? Not much really.

Comment: @Deduplicator from the looks of the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple it seems like the function gets called again every time i want another value out of it, is that true?

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree with your sentiment :) But letting OP know one potential convention that addresses this issue.

Comment: @Pradhan Mentioning a bad convention is of little merit.  I worry it might just cause confusion.

Comment: @user81993: I don't quite get what your comment is asking about...

Comment: Small functions like these I would write using `std::transform` and a lambda.

Comment: @Deduplicator lets say the function I'm calling is computationally expensive and produces 2 output values through an interwoven process, in that case when i do the tuple thing, does the function get ran twice or just once?

Comment: Naturally once for the whole tuple, and you get to process it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a preprocessor directive:

```
#define OUT
```

and put it in the parameter list like so:

```
void doStuff(vector<int> &a, int b, OUT vector<int> &c) ...
```

I think I've seen some APIs do something like this. That way it is explicitly stated in the function signature but you don't have to modify the variable names. The code is also unchanged at compile time since OUT is not defined to be anything, it is just a defined symbol.

I think, though, I would rely on your own documentation when writing the function and/or return-by-value instead of doing something like this. You could also make use of the `const` keyword to flag a parameter that is guaranteed not to change - that's what the syntax is designed for.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax, by itself, can be a guide to indicate which one is an input argument and which one is an output argument. However, an output argument can also serve as an input argument too. You cannot tell that by just looking at the signature.

Examples:

```
int foo(int arg); // The argument is copy by value. It can only be an input argument.

void foo(std::vector<int> const& arg); // The argument is by const&.
                                       // It can only be an input argument.

void foo(std::vector<int>& arg); // The argument is by &. It can be:
                                 // 1) an output argument.
                                 // 2) an input and output argument.
                                 // 3) an input argument (bad practice)
```

Comment: Last example could also be a (bad) input-argument. Only as an in-out-argument it is good form though.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I didn't even think about it being an input argument. Like you said, it is bad but it can happen.